# How I can add a counter after adding a new <li> to my list using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to implement a dynamic counter to add into my list after adding a new row on the top of my list. 
The code is not working properly because it count wrong for example if we have this list

1. A
2. B
3. C

and i will add the D instead of make it like this

1. D
2. A
3. B
4. C

is do it like this

2. D
3. A
4. B
5. C

Last i want to remove the last row if I add a new row on the bottom but is not working
Does anyone knows why?

Here is my code

html a variable that holds the contents that I want to prepend

```
$(".il_admin-"+id).prepend(html).slideDown("slow");​

var i = GetURLParameter("paged");
var count = (i*10)-10;
jQuery(".il_admin li").each(function(i) {
i = count + i;
var text_attreibute = $(this).find(".il_admin_raw_count");
$(text_attreibute).html(i+1);
});

var size= $('.il_admin li').size();

if (size >10)
{
var last_row = $('.il_admin li').last().attr('class');
$(last_row).remove();
}
```

Comment: what comes in i by "paged"????

Comment: is the page number on the url. for example if the paged is 1 the first li will be 1, if the paged is 2 the first li will be 11 and so on

Comment: before this $(text_attreibute).html(i+1); . i already have a value 1 then you incrementing it by 1.Please have a look !

Comment: this one is correct i = count + i; because if i is 1 then count = (1*10) = 10 and then count= 10-10 = 0. then i = 0+0 = 0. so i'm adding 1 on the .html. if you load the website this method is working fine. but if you try to prepend and then execute the code to count the rows having the new row is not count it correctly. adds first the 2 and then the 1,3,4 ...

Comment: You have a list, the contents of which you want to be numbered? Why are you using JavaScript, when `ol li { list-style-type: decimal; }` will do this for you automatically? Or even `ul li`, or simply `li` (with the same CSS rule)?

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(".il_admin li").each(function() {
    var text_attreibute = $(this).find(".il_admin_raw_count");
    $(this).html(parseInt($(this).index())+1 + '. ' + text_attreibute);
});
```

Since you use long-polling, you have to bind a listenner on the change of your list in order to refresh the index. Try this :

```
jQuery(document).on("change", ".il_admin", function(i, list_li) {
    // This will be call each time your DOM inside your .il_admin change (= you have added a new line)

    $(list_li).each(function(j, li) {
        var text_attreibute = $(li).find(".il_admin_raw_count");
        var output = parseInt($(li).index())+1 + '. ' + text_attreibute;
        if (output != $(li).html()) { // We change the content only if the index has changed like this we avoid infinit loop because we will change the html again and it could call our listener again
            $(li).html(output);
        }
    }

}).
```

Comment: using this solution if i add a new row then i have 1. D 1. A 2. B 3. C . I try to print the parseInt($(this).index())+1 and it is correct but on the website doesn't show it in the right order

Comment: You have to call `$(this).html(parseInt($(this).index())+1);` not only at `$(document).ready();` but each time the user add a line too. Like this you will see the right order.

Comment: this is what i'm doing. basically the $(".il_admin-"+id).prepend(html).slideDown("slow");​ is in an if statement and then outside the if statement i have the code to re-calculate the list, but is still not working

Comment: Show me how you call your re-calculate. With a listener or something ?

Comment: basically the $(".il_admin-"+id).prepend(html).slideDown("slow");​ is inside an if statement, if(condition){}else{$(".il_admin-"+id).prepend(html).slideDown("slow");​} and then i'm having the .each to renumber each li

Comment: Ok, but you have to call `$(this).html(parseInt($(this).index())+1);` from a listener. I don't know how do you add a new line, if you do it with a button, you can do :
$(document).on('click', '#my_button_id', function() {

})

Comment: basically the new line is added by a long-polling

Comment: I don't know what is a long-polling. By the way, you just have to call what I show you just right after you insert the new line. Simply putting it in a if do not refresh the index, you have to use a listener.

Comment: the refresh of the index is outside the if statement and is called automatically every time when the if statement is executed and finished

Comment: Look at my Edit to the answer. Do not remove your old code, this is to put in addition to the other code.

Comment: the problem was on $(".il_admin-"+id).prepend(html).slideDown("slow");​ i had to add parent().prepend in order to work properly

Answer (score 0):

In order to work the solution was to change this line

`$(".il_admin-"+id).prepend(html).slideDown("slow");`​

to this

```
$(".il_admin-"+id).parent().prepend(html).slideDown("slow");​
```